# In Powershell, how to make the zip output name the same as the input name

Tags: powershell, zip, output, compression, archive

I'm writing a simple ps1 script to automatically zip up log files to their own individual zip archives (I'll ultimately use Task Scheduler to schedule), and I want the output name to be the same as the input name (e.g. Log_20210309.log > Log_20210309.zip)

I feel like I'm so close. The below example looks for *.log files with yesterday's date in the filename, and where I need help is piping the filename to the zip output filename.

```
$Input = "C:\Script\Input\"
$Output = "C:\Scripts\Output\"

Get-ChildItem $Input -Filter *$((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')).log | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output$_.FileName -Force
```

The `Get-ChildItem` part seems to work OK (the script works if I replace everything after the pipe with `Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output -Force`, but the output filename will be blank (".zip")). I've tried dozens of variations of the piped section, including:

```
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output + $_.FileName -Force
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output + "$_.FileName" -Force
ForEach-Object { Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output"$_.FileName" -Force }
ForEach-Object { Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $Output + "$_.FileName" -Force }
```

and so on...

Comment: Don't use `$input` as variable name as it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script uses variables for the source directory, destination directory, and filename extension to compress. When it is compressing the correct files, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Compress-Archive` command.

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\Script\Input'
$OutputDir = 'C:\Script\Output'
$Extension = '.log'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $SourceDir -Filter $('*' + $Extension) |
    ForEach-Object {
        Compress-Archive `
            -DestinationPath (Join-Path $OutputDir $($_.BaseName + '.zip')) `
            -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `*.txt` instead of `*.log` for this example. This works fine:

```
$destinationPath="$PSScriptRoot\Output"

ls "$PSScriptRoot\input\*.txt"|%{ 
    $fileName=$_.Name -replace '.txt','.zip'
    Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath "$destinationPath\$fileName" -CompressionLevel Optimal
}
```